# Is there truly free of charge or open source electronic grade book for teachers/schools/parents?

Tags: gratis, educational

I am writing a seminar dissertation about new educational tools. I covered few tools which enhance fast learning but now I want to write about electronic grade book. I am Master of IT and this is part of extracurricular course.

I am from Poland and here every solution on the market has hidden fees, premium modules etc. I have been looking for English solutions but I couldn't find any free of charge or open source projects.

**Question:** Is there any electronic grade book which is **open source** or at least **free of charge** which enables:

- remembering grades
- remembering presence of children
- parents notification if student is absent
- chart analyse/tendency in student's scores
- analysing SAT and others exams' results
- localization (not only language but grade and exam system as well)
- uploading homework

Or maybe is there electronic grade book provided by US Government for primary/secondary/high schools?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend **[Canvas](http://instructure.com)**.

Canvas is a [learning management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system) that supports most of the features that you have noted in your post.

It supports

- online assignments (from paper submissions to simple text to file upload to online quizzes),
- attendance features including tracking absence and tardiness, and (AFAIK) allowing parents to subscribe to attendance emails,
- classroom pages and announcements,
- an online gradebook that supports both assignments submitted online and in class (manual entry),
- the ability to look at statistics toward progressing toward specific outcomes, and
- the ability to do online conferencing, for free.

There are three ways to get the dual-licensed (both commercial and open-source) product:

- **Institutions** can subscribe to the [institution-wide, hosted version of Canvas](http://www.instructure.com/affordability).
- **Instructors** can create a free account on the [public (Free-for-Instructor) implementation of Canvas](http://canvas.instructure.com/).
- Additionally, you may download the [open-source version of Canvas](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki) and install it onto a POSIX-based server (Mac or Linux).